# Dotnet Isolated ServiceBusTrigger connection string setup with Azure App Configuration

Tags: .net, azure, .net-7.0, azure-app-configuration

I've just switched from dotnet  in proccess project to isolated one, but now I have problem with configuring connection string in my ServiceBusTrigger.

Program.cs

```
var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration(builder =>
        builder
            .AddAzureAppConfiguration(options =>
            {
                options.Connect(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(CommonConfigurationConstants.AppConfigurationConnectionString))
                    .Select(KeyFilter.Any, LabelFilter.Null)
                    .Select(KeyFilter.Any, ConfigurationConstants.AppLabel)
                    .ConfigureKeyVault(kv =>
                    {
                        kv.SetCredential(new DefaultAzureCredential());
                    })
                    .ConfigureRefresh(refreshOptions =>
                        refreshOptions.Register(CommonConfigurationConstants.SentinelKey, refreshAll: true))
                        .UseFeatureFlags();
            })
            .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", true))
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
    .ConfigureServices(s =>
    {
        s.ConfigureMediatR()
            .ConfigureAutomapper()
            .ConfigureFluentValidations()
            .ConfigureServices()
            .ConfigureRepositories()
            .ConfigureDatabase();
        s.AddFeatureManagement();
    })
    .Build();

host.Run();
```

SampleFunction.cs

```
public class SampleFunction
    {
        [Function("SampleFunction")]
        public async Task Run(
            [ServiceBusTrigger(
                "sampleTopic",
                "sampleSubscription",
                Connection = "QueueConnectionString",
                IsSessionsEnabled = true)]
            BaseQueueRequest req, string messageId)
        {
               ...
        }
    }
```

I added QueueConnectionString to my Azure App Configuration, but still, if I'll not place it in local.settings.json application does not start.
Question is - is there a way to setup this connection string in Azure App Configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression resolution from middleware is not supported in isolated Azure Functions. This is tracked in https://github.com/Azure/AppConfiguration/issues/203.

Comment: ok, thanks, I hope they will fix it soon :)